# how to download file in react native

Tags: react-native, download, background-process, android-download-manager

How can I download files in react native having functionality such as-

- Start
- Resume
- Stop
- background running support

I have tried a few of the packages, some support background download(IOS only), some do not allow to stop download, some of them are very old, and so on.

Comment: Try: `react-native-background-downloader`

Comment: doesn't work. It does not show download in background/notification drawer

Comment: You can use `react-native-background-downloader` and `react-native-push-notification` to display a notification when a download is in progress in the background.

Comment: Here in react native push notification does not accept any parameter for showing progress, it is just a message I guess.

Comment: In that case, you can use: `react-native-progress`